# How can we find real source of suspected user entries?

Tags: ip-address, hacking, user-agent, proxy

I have a website where I keep logging the user entries. I found some anonymous entries in my table and I suspect they are using some kind of proxy switchers. How can I find the real source of these intruders?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "user entry", what are your referring to?  It could be an entry in your log file or the entrance of a visitor into the site.

Comment: What makes you think that these visitors are "intruders"?  Are they somehow malicious?   Almost all websites get anonymous visitors.  Why would you expect to know who all your visitors are?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, i have a log which keeps user details like ip, user-agent etc. I found a number of suspicious ips  from different locations of the world in a limited span of time, where my site is not meant for global users. So i suspect someone is using proxy switcher and trying to hack.

Comment: Hackers also use bot-nets and other hacked web sites from around the world as their base for attacks.  It doesn't have to be proxies.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for the info, but here i am looking for a solution to find out someone using a proxy switcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user is using a proxy, there may be headers in the request that you could examine or log to let you know what the original IP address of the user is. See:

- [X-Originating-IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Originating-IP)
- [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

If you are using Apache server, headers such as this can be logged using `%{header}i`, in the [log format configuration directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) where "header" can be any HTTP request header.

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible. You can try a few clever tricks that may or may not work (caching a flash object and checking for it to identify if a user is using multiple IPs, or carefully tracking several user details and looking for matches).  It's better to just make sure the site is secure versus trying to track users at all.